# questions about combinations of React useEffect, useEffect cleanup and eventlistener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-listener

**Browser console logs below:**
page is rendered
page is rendered---------------------------VM315 installHook.js:1861
App.js:65 scroll event listener is added(mark it as NUM1)
App.js:68 scroll event listener is removed(mark it as NUM2)
App.js:65 scroll event listener is added(mark it as NUM3)

At the initial rendering, click event listener is added(NUM1), skipping callback function "calculateOffset" then when exiting the useEffect, the click event is removed(NUM2).
I could understand until this part, **am I right?**
**But why after all these above, console logged one more time event listener is added(NUM3)...**
The result is actually needed and helpful, if not I can't basically trigger the event listener anymore
with clicking. But why, I wonder during which stage the useEffect is triggered and second event listener is added.
I don't think the Second time useEffect is trigged because of the dimension is changed, I think during the first time useEffect, the calculateOffset is not runed and the dimensions
Stayed therefore the initial value which is empty object. Is the problem here?**Do I understanded wrong?**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState,useRef,useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({});
  const block = useRef(null);

  const calculateOffset = () => {
   
    console.log(block.current.getBoundingClientRect());
    const {top,height,width} =
    block.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    

    setDimensions({ top, height, width});
    console.log("dimentions setted");
    
    // console.log(top, height, windowInnerHeight, togglePoint);
    
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("click event listener is added");
    window.addEventListener("click", calculateOffset);
    return () => {
      console.log("click event listener is removed");
      window.removeEventListener("click", calculateOffset);
    };
  },[dimensions]);

  console.log("page is rendered");
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='block' ref={block} ></div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default App
```

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container{
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;

  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

PS: As the useEffect called an event listener, how the useEffect will behavior if the event listener is not triggered/used, for example
Will the Event Listener just hang there and wait until the user click, then useEffect clean up come into play which will clean the click event listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("click event listener is added");
    window.addEventListener("click", calculateOffset);
    return () => {
      console.log("click event listener is removed");
      window.removeEventListener("click", calculateOffset);
    };
  },[dimensions]);
```

Checked how the UseEffect works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Strict Mode", i.e. development mode, components render twice on first mount and for every state change. Thus, when the component first mounts, the component useEffect will render twice, even if there has not been a state change to `dimensions`. This means the clean up function will run on the second render, and the event listener will be added again:

```
page is rendered (x2)
click event listener is added 
click event listener is removed 
click event listener is added
```

Then, because in your `useEffect` you have the `dimensions` in your dependency array, the `useEffect` will then only be run after the user clicks and the dimensions change (even if there are other state changes because the `useEffect` only depends on the state of `dimensions`).

Thus after each click, the old event listener will be removed, and a new one added. And you will only see this after each click:

```
page is rendered (x2)
click event listener is removed 
click event listener is added
```

You can now see that although the page is rendering twice like on the first mount, the useEffect listener is only being added once.